# Search in SVN Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using Subversive plugin for Eclipse to connect to SVN Code repository.
Our code base is so huge, that am finding it difficult to search for files.
I am not able to find files using Ctrl+F key also.
Is there anyway I can search for specific files in this plugin.
thanks in advance,

Regards,
PK

Comment: That feature would be great. Please update the thread if you find a usable solution

Comment: Checkout the whole code base and use Eclipse's Open Resource function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NO there is no search function in subversive (and not in svn either).

You can do a small workaround:

```
svn ls -R [YOUR_PROJECT_REPO_URL] > all_files.txt
```

will list all files in your repo into the file all_files.txt (**Caution:** This will take some time..maybe start it of friday and let it run through the weekend..). After retreiving the file you can just search via your favorite texteditor(or eclipse).

Sure this is just a workaround, and you can not update this textfile in shorter time, but if you do not rely on most current versions it is a workaround